# Bulk copy files over sftp with a delay between each file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to move my files from one directory to SFTP and further to another directory in sequence not together.

Let's say if my directories are A and B.

Here is my code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cp -R /usr/sap/tmp/Dir A/. /usr/sap/tmp/Dir B/
lftp <<_EOF_
open sftp://User:Password@Host -p Port
lcd /usr/sap/tmp/Dir A
cd /
pwd
mput -E /usr/sap/tmp/Dir A/*.dat
exit
_EOF_
```

This works fine. But the only problem is it moves all files together at the same time from dir A to SFTP. How can I get it to move files one by one (in sequence, say the files moved to SFTP should have at least difference of one second between them)?

Comment: Doesn't work fine as given; when you have directories named `Dir A` and `Dir B` with spaces, you need to perform quoting to distinguish spaces within the names from spaces that separate names.

Comment: that said... you're asking for mput to delay between files? That strikes me as an unusual request; you may need to switch away from mput to a series of individual `put`s. BTW, you can efficiently start a separate copy of lftp for each file (letting you do things like wait between the individual lftp instances) if you configure the ssh `ControlMaster` and `ControlSocket` settings to allow a single transport to be shared across distinct commands.

Comment: BTW, unless you configure lftp to parallelize (which it can indeed do, but IIRC doesn't do with mput as an out-of-the-box default), it's _not_ copying files concurrently -- it's just copying them in sequence very quickly without a delay between them.

Comment: ...have you thought about fixing whatever software can't handle multiple files appearing within the same second, instead of "fixing" your file transfer by slowing it down?

Comment: You can make a script that will use a list of `.dat` files and generate all the `lftp` commands with a `!sleep 1` between each file.

Comment: Hi Charles   

You are correct I just wrote to give an example.

#!/bin/bash
cp -R /usr/sap/tmp/DirA/. /usr/sap/tmp/DirB/
lftp <<_EOF_
open sftp://User:Password@Host -p Port
lcd /usr/sap/tmp/DirA
cd /
pwd
mput -E /usr/sap/tmp/DirA/*.dat
exit
_EOF_

Can you pls write in code what needs to be done to move files in sequence & not together to SFTP? I m not into networking/scripting but searching for answer.

Regards

Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

First create a file with commands for all files.

```
cat <<@ > inputfile
open sftp://User:Password@Host -p Port
lcd /usr/sap/tmp/Dir A
cd /
pwd
@

find . -type f -name sa\*.txt -print0 |
  xargs -n1 --null -I'{}' printf "%s\n" "mput '{}'" '!'"sleep 1" >> inputfile
echo "exit" >> inputfile
```

Next stream that file

```
lftp << inputfile
```